# Use uniq inside range on hugo template

Tags: go, hugo

I have a sorted range

```
{{ range sort . "id" "asc" }}
    {{ .topic.name }}
{{ end }}
```

but `.topic.name` has a lot of repeated names, and I want to get show only one of each.

I find the [uniq](https://gohugo.io/functions/uniq/) function on Hugo, but can't find the right syntax to use it.

I had tried:

```
{{ range sort . "id" "asc" }}
    {{ slice .topic.name | uniq }}
{{ end }}
```

and:

```
{{ range sort . "id" "asc" }}
    {{ uniq (slice .topic.name) }}
{{ end }}
```

and:

```
{{ range sort . "id" "asc" }}
    {{ uniq .topic.name }}
{{ end }}
```

And some other variations. Also searched in the examples of Hugo documentation and repository examples with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a slice to store the already displayed values (topic names). Before each print operation, check whether the value has already been printed or not. If it hasn't, store the currently printed name in the slice.

```
{{ $displayedNames := slice }}
{{ range sort . "id" "asc" }}
    {{ if not (in $displayedNames .topic.name) }}
        {{ .topic.name }}
        {{ $displayedNames = $displayedNames | append .topic.name }}
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```